# Compare 2 periods in SQL Server in the same table

Tags: sql-server

[image]

[image]

the resulte coming in 2 select need it in one resulte

I have one table need to compare sales for same branch in last yearm which is in SQL Server. Any help appreciated.

```
DECLARE @fdate as date
DECLARE @secdate as date

SET @fdate = '01-01-2020'; 
SET @secdate = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 110)); 

SELECT
    trans.STORE As 'Store Number' ,
    (SUM (trans.NETAMOUNT * -1)) AS sales2019
FROM
    RETAILTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS AS trans 
WHERE
    trans.TRANSDATE BETWEEN @fdate AND @secdate 
GROUP BY
    trans.STORE


SELECT
    trans.STORE AS 'Store Number' ,
    (SUM (trans.NETAMOUNT * -1)) AS sales2018
FROM
    RETAILTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS AS trans 
WHERE
    trans.TRANSDATE between  DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @fdate) and DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @secdate)  -- same reply Form Mr. marc_s
GROUP BY
    trans.STORE
```

Comment: Don't use `@fdate-365` - first of all - unclear if that is 365 days, or hours, or minutes.... also: doesn't handle leap years. Use `DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @fdate)`  instead

Comment: Mr. marc_s Plz Can you see the post the issue coming in 2 results i need in one result

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wanted both the result to appear side by side ?

You can use conditional case statement to do that

```
DECLARE @fdate as date
DECLARE @secdate as date

SET @fdate = '20200101'; 
SET @secdate = GETDATE();

SELECT
    trans.STORE As 'Store Number' ,
    SUM (CASE WHEN trans.TRANSDATE BETWEEN @fdate 
                                       AND @secdate 
              THEN trans.NETAMOUNT * -1 END) AS sales2019,
    SUM (CASE WHEN trans.TRANSDATE BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @fdate) 
                                       AND DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @secdate) 
              THEN trans.NETAMOUNT * -1 END) AS sales2018
FROM
    RETAILTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS AS trans 
WHERE
    trans.TRANSDATE BETWEEN @fdate 
                        AND @secdate 
OR  trans.TRANSDATE BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @fdate) 
                        AND DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @secdate)
GROUP BY
    trans.STORE
```

Note : You don't have to convert `GETDATE()` to string before assigning to `@secdate`, since `@secdate`is a `date` data type.
Also is is best to specify the date string literal in YYYYMMDD format